# an issue of getting Matrix for training sift features

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, sift

I have extracted the features by using OpenCV opensource..

I have done these steps by using these 2 functions

```
SiftFeatureDetector
SiftDescriptorExtractor
```

which I got a matrix of 128*128 from the descriptors, which I think as well that I will use
this matrix to train the features...

What I'm confused about is the following,

When I want to train the features, 
I should use a matrix of number of features and every single row contains the information about that feature.. which it might be a matrix of

```
number of features * 6
```

For example, I got 344 features in an image... and I got a matrix of 128*128 for the descriptor, which I need this matrix in order to train my features

but as I mentioned, I'm just getting 128*128 matrix.. so what's the problem?

And, what should I get to train later on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp), or the [matcher_simple.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/matcher_simple.cpp) samples from OpenCV? Also, could you post the code you are using to detect the features?

Comment: Yeah, I can post my code, I have used these methods... I know they are better in classification part, but can you show me how to train the features from the matched images?

Comment: Sure! Post your code, and I'll have a look at it this evening.

Comment: thanks in advanced, I have added my code, it has some mess :$, anyways, I want you to show me what should I do in order to let me train my features which I will use them later on in SVM